# Product inventory database with attributes and variants

Tags: python, database, django

I have design a model for product apps. This is the first time I am trying to create a product's database schema and then model it in Django. My code handles the following:

1. A product type can have multiple products and each product type can have certain attributes in common. Examples of product types can be clothing, accessories and bags.
2. A product can have zero or more attributes, like color, size and material.
3. Each attribute will have multiple values.
4. A product can have multiple combination of variants and each variant has their own stock quantity and price.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from mptt.managers import TreeManager
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="type of product. ex - accessories, clothing")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    is_shipping_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("slug",)
        app_label = "product"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # description_json = JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    objects = models.Manager()
    tree = TreeManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name="products",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    article_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name = "product"
      verbose_name_plural = "products"
      ordering = ("name",)
      constraints = [
          models.UniqueConstraint(
              fields=["article_number", "slug"], name="unique article number and slug")
      ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.article_number}'

class Attribute(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class AttributeValue(models.Model):
  attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  value = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.value


class ProductAttributeValue(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  attribute_value = models.ForeignKey(AttributeValue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductTypeAttributeValue(models.Model):
  product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  attribute_value = models.ForeignKey(AttributeValue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductVariant(models.Model):
  sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  track_inventory = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.sku

class ProductVariantValues(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  value = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttributeValue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)




class CollectionProduct(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        "Collection", related_name="collectionproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="collectionproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("collection", "product"),)

    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        return self.product.collectionproduct.all()


class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        blank=True,
        related_name="collections",
        through=CollectionProduct,
        through_fields=("collection", "product"),
    )
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("slug",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Due to my lack of experience with databases I am not quite sure if the design is sound. Can anyone verify if there is any room for improvement for the relationships between product, product variants and attributes? I especially would like to see how how it can be designed in a better way. For example relationships, like `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`, normalization, query complexity and scalability.

Update

I have this on repl as well

https://repl.it/@tushantk/HumiliatingInterestingMarketing#product/models.py

Comment: Please include your `import`s

Comment: @Reinderien. Thanks for your comment. I have included the import's and also the link where I have this code running.